# How to display twitter and instagram @ (usernames) as a profile name with meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to make a variable to choose from 2 differents values, if one is null then select the other.

```
author: '@'+ user.services.instagram.username.toUpperCase() || user.services.twitter.screenName.toUpperCase()
```

This results in an error when I try to comment on a Twitter account.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instagram' of undefined
```

Here a snap code

```
comment = _.extend(commentAttributes, {
  userId: user._id,
  // author: '@'+user.services.instagram.username.toUpperCase(),
  author: '@'+ user.services.instagram.username.toUpperCase() || user.services.twitter.screenName.toUpperCase(),
  submitted: formatDate(new Date())
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was trying to pull @ handles of instagram and twitter with the 'same' variable, so I can use it as a profile name. The problem was Instagram is using services.instagram.username and Twitter is using services.twitter.screenName

I could fix this editing the meteor packages but that is not a complete solution, instead I made a condition for 'Account.onCreateUser' [based on this](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Merging_OAuth_accounts).

So I just made that profile.name is saving user @ instead of name.

```
        if (service == 'instagram') {
            if (!user.profile)
                user.profile = {};
            if (!user.profile.name)
                user.profile.name = user.services[service].username;
        }

        if (service == 'twitter') {
          if (!user.profile)
                user.profile = {};
          if (!user.profile.name)
                user.profile.name = user.services[service].screenName;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your error message simply says that your `user.services` variable is `undefined`.
2. `'@' + null` gives `'@null'`, so it is always truthy.

Comment: user.services is not null, I can use user.services.twitter or user.services.instagram just fine. What I’m trying to do is if “Instagram is null then use Twitter”. 

Please don’t downvote just for fun.

Comment: Why do you assume that I downvoted? I do not downvote and answer.

Comment: As for `user.services` being not null, you show no proof of that. You may try to access it while it is still undefined. It may be true that it is not null, but without further details from your side, the above answer is the most probable explanation for the issue you describe.